# Hard Problems for higher genus graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Planar graphs have genus zero. Graphs embeddable on a torus have genus at most 1. My question is simple :

- Are there any problems that are polynomially solvable on planar graphs but NP-hard on graphs of genus one ?
- More generally are there any problems that are polynomially solvable on graphs of genus g but NP-hard on graphs of genus > g ?

Comment: For the second question, do you want the problem to be NP-hard for graphs of genus >= k, where k is a constant greater than g? OR do you just want the problem to be NP-hard for graphs whose genus isn't less than g (which is equivalent to it being NP-hard for general graphs)?

Comment: I am looking for NP-Hard problems for graphs of genus >= k, where k is a constant greater than g.

Answer (score 16):

This is publicity of my own work, but crossing number and 1-planarity are trivially solvable in planar graphs but hard for graphs of genus one. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5944

Comment: "A graph is near-planar if it can be obtained from a planar graph by adding an edge. A graph is 1-planar if it has a drawing where every edge is crossed by at most one other edge. We show that it is NP-hard to decide whether a given near-planar graph is 1-planar." I must be missing something.  Why isn't every near-planar graph also 1-planar?

Comment: What I think you're saying is that you can just take a planar embedding of $G-e$ and add the edge back in. However, that extra edge could cross more than one edge, violating 1-planarity.

Comment: @TimothySun Yes.  Every edge other than $e$ will be crossed at most once (by $e$), but $e$ could be crossed by more than one other edge, which is not allowed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If toy problems are fine:

Let $g\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $H$ be some graph of genus $g+1$. For $\phi$ a CNF-formula, let $G_\phi$ be some encoding of $\phi$ as a planar graph *plus* a disjoint copy of $H$.

Given $G_\phi$, which is a graph of genus $g+1$, it is NP-hard to decide whether $\phi$ is satisfiable. This problem however becomes trivial when restricted to graphs of genus $\leq g$.

Comment: what is this problem on graphs of genus $\leq g$

Comment: All graphs $G_\phi$ have genus $g+1$. Thus, if you restrict the problem to graphs of genus $g$, you can always reject.

Comment: ah, it becomes *really* trivial, I see

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT (2012-09-05):** Jeff's and Radu's comments are right. The cited result does not answer the question. To expand on Radu's comment, here is a related algorithm by [Bravyi](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.0683.pdf) which gives an algorithm for contracting matchgate tensors on a graph $G$ with genus $g$ with run-time $T=poly(n) + 2^{2g} O(m^3)$ where $m$ is the minimum number of edges one has to remove from $G$ in order to make it planar.

---

[Cai, Lu, and Xia](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.0683.pdf) recently proved the following dichotomy for #CSP counting problems:

> We prove complexity dichotomy theorems in the framework of counting
>   CSP problems. The local constraint functions take Boolean inputs, and
>   can be arbitrary real-valued symmetric functions. We prove that, every
>   problem in this class belongs to precisely three categories:
>
> (1) those which are tractable (i.e., polynomial time computable) on
>   general graphs, or
>   (2) those which are **#P-hard on general graphs but
>   tractable on planar graphs**, or
>   (3) those which are #P-hard even on
>   planar graphs.
>
> The classication criteria are explicit.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Can category (2) can be split into (2a) tractable for planar graphs but #P-hard for toroidal graphs, and (2b) tractable for bounded-genus graphs but #P-hard for unbounded-genus graphs?

Comment: Case (2) consists of problems that can be reduced to counting perfect matchings in planar graphs by introducing local planar gadgets. It is [also known](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_6/PDF/v6i1r6.pdf) that perfect matchings can be counted in polynomial time on bounded-genus graphs. Thus, _all_ problems in case (2) are actually tractable on bounded-genus graphs.

Answer (score 2):

For any fixed $g$, there is a polynomial-time algorithm to determine whether a graph has genus (at most) $g$.  Let $X_g$  be any problem that is NP-complete on graphs of genus greater than $g$ (e.g., 3-colourability).  For each fixed $g$, the problem "Does the input graph have genus at most $g$ or is it in $X_g$ (or both)?" is NP-complete for general input but has a polynomial-time algorithm when the input is restricted to graphs of genus at most $g$.

This idea can be used quite generally to produce problems that are "hard" on general graphs but "easy" on some class $\mathcal C$ of graphs, as long as it is "easy" to determine membership in $\mathcal C$.