# MSO properties, planar graphs and minor-free graphs

Tags: graph-theory, lo.logic, treewidth, planar-graphs, graph-minor

[Courcelle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courcelle%27s_theorem) states that every graph property definable in [monadic second-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_second-order_logic#Syntax) can be decided in linear time on graphs of bounded [treewidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth). This is one of the most well-known algorithmic meta-theorems.

Motivated by Courcelle's theorem, I made the following conjecture :

> **Conjecture** : Let $\psi$ be any MSO-definable property. If $\psi$ is solvable in polynomial-time on planar graphs, then $\psi$ is solvable in polynomial-time on all classes of minor-free graphs.

I want to know if the above conjecture is obviously false i.e., is there an MSO-definable property that is polynomial-time solvable on planar graphs but NP-hard on some class of minor-free graphs ?

This is the motivation behind my [earlier question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12490/hard-problems-for-higher-genus-graphs) : Are there any problems that are polynomially solvable on graphs of genus g but NP-hard on graphs of genus > g.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Being 4-colorable?  Certainly MSO, and trivial on planar graphs.  It's NP-complete for a large enough forbidden clique minor, by reduction to planar 3-colorability.

Comment: More explicitly, 4-colorability is NP-complete on the minor-closed family of apex graphs, by reduction to planar 3-colorability.