Problems hard on toroidal graphs that are polytime on planar
Are there any known (natural) problems that are polynomial time solvable on planar graphs, but NP-complete on toroidal graphs?
I'm not looking for problems like 4-Coloring, Planar Vertex Deletion, Crossing Number, or other problems that are "always true" on planar graphs due to structural reasons.

This was already asked with some useful answers/discussion. See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12490/hard-problems-for-higher-genus-graphs

Thank you very much, @ChandraChekuri, I didn't find that question.  I think the question is still interesting, almost 12 years later, and it seems like the answer to the question is no.
